# SQLite SQL error or missing database (no such table)

Tags: sqlite

Hi everyone I am having some problems with my SQLite database in my java program. I am trying to retrieve data from a couple of tables but it says my table doesn't exist. I have checked using DB Browser and it's definitely there, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the error I receive:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: staff_clocked_in.clock_in_time)

```
SELECT * FROM staff, staff_clocked_in.clock_in_time WHERE staff.staff_id = staff_clocked_in.staff_id;
```

I'm sure my tables exist and there is data in both tables, here is a screenshot of my db browser.

[image]

If it helps, this is how I have setup my tables:

STAFF:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (staff_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, first_name TEXT NOT NULL, last_name TEXT NOT NULL, job_title TEXT NOT NULL);
```

STAFF_CLOCKED_IN:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff_clocked_in (staff_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES staff(staff_id), clock_in_time DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with my query? I'm not good with databases so hopefully it's just something simple.

Comment: In your FROM staff_clocked_in.clock_in_time is not a table. It should be just staff_clocked_in

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve it using your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is correct `staff_clocked_in.clock_in_time` is not a table.

You should use `staff_clocked_in` instead which is your table.

So the fixed query should look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM staff, staff_clocked_in 
WHERE staff.staff_id = staff_clocked_in.staff_id;
```